# How to restrict user role to see only their members profile?

Tags: users, group

I am using [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module and I created a new role: moderator

Here's my group:

- Company A - Moderator role
- Company A1 - Member role
- Company A2 - Member role

How can I restrict the companies profile view of the members?

Company A with moderator role should be allowed to see **only** the members profile of its group. Company A1 with member role can only see its own profile.

And that goes for company B, B1, B2 etc of another group.

For example: Company A, can't see Company B1 user profile because it doesn't belong to its group.

How can I achieve this? I tried in the Moderator permissions but i can still see other companies profile if I just change it in the url.